# Neural network for pattern recognition

Tags: neural-network, encog

I want you to help me figure out which problem am I dealing with (pattern recognition or time series forecasting) and find the best NN architecture suited for this problem.

In my problem, I have many finite sets of **two dimensional** data (learning sets)
Lets **N** be the size of the data set I want to calculate using the NN.
I want my NN to learn these data and by giving it the first **m** data of the data set it gives me the remaining **N-m** data.

I think it's rather a pattern recognition problem, so which is the best NN architecture suited for this kind.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have understood you problem, you have a dataset with N rows. And you want to train your network using first M rows. And then you want your NN to predict the rest N-M rows.

Typically, in **forecasting (timeseries prediction)**, we do this kind of stuffs. We train our model with historical data and try to predict future values.

So, in your case, top M rows could be training data in the training phase.And during the model accuracy evaluation phase, future values could be your N-M rows.

Typically, **recurrent networks** are best suited for temporal data, because, they can take care of ordered data.
ENCOG also provides a special dataset for temporal data.And you can use them for your problem.